# How can I filter an array of objects between two dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Aside from the occasional jQuery selectors and element modifications, I'm not too great at javascript. For a problem I'm having, I need to filter out a javascript object by date. I have a structure that looks like this:

```
Object { version: "3.1.1", released_on: "2016-08-21T00:00:00.000Z", high_vulns: 15, medium_vulns: 10, low_vulns: 5 }
```

I want to find all of the objects from 10 years so between `"2016-08-21T00:00:00.000Z"` and `"2010-08-21T00:00:00.000Z"` The problem I'm experiencing is that the `released_on:` field is a string not a date. Would I need to create a `new Date()` object convert it into a string, and then use `.filter` or would I do the opposite, convert the string into a date and then filter. Has anyone tried something like this before?

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` will give you a number that will be easier to work with

Comment: put this in browser console `console.log(new Date("2016-08-21T00:00:00.000Z"))` will see that your date strings are perfectly valid. Can even use comparison operators directly on date objects

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might do as follows;

```js
var data = [{ version: "3.1.1", released_on: "2016-08-21T00:00:00.000Z", high_vulns: 15, medium_vulns: 10, low_vulns: 5 },
            { version: "3.1.1", released_on: "2011-08-21T00:00:00.000Z", high_vulns: 15, medium_vulns: 10, low_vulns: 5 },
            { version: "3.1.1", released_on: "2009-08-21T00:00:00.000Z", high_vulns: 15, medium_vulns: 10, low_vulns: 5 },
            { version: "3.1.1", released_on: "2006-08-21T00:00:00.000Z", high_vulns: 15, medium_vulns: 10, low_vulns: 5 },
            { version: "3.1.1", released_on: "2013-08-21T00:00:00.000Z", high_vulns: 15, medium_vulns: 10, low_vulns: 5 },
            { version: "3.1.1", released_on: "2017-08-21T00:00:00.000Z", high_vulns: 15, medium_vulns: 10, low_vulns: 5 },
            { version: "3.1.1", released_on: "2015-08-21T00:00:00.000Z", high_vulns: 15, medium_vulns: 10, low_vulns: 5 },
           ],
      ed = new Date("2016-08-21T00:00:00.000Z").getTime(),
      sd = new Date("2010-08-21T00:00:00.000Z").getTime(),
  result = data.filter(d => {var time = new Date(d.released_on).getTime();
                             return (sd < time && time < ed);
                            });
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const filterBetweenDates = (data, setState, fromDate, toDate) => {
  try {
    setState(data.filter(({ date }) => date >= fromDate && date <= toDate));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error while filtering by dates', error.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.