# Filter by date Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this question is already solved in this post [FilterbyDate][1] but I'm fetching a local json file, I need to filter the json file with the date range of an input text. I have a localserver, so I already fetched the json file and display it with a console.log

The date structure is like this one "2020-02-01", I think that if I could assign the json fetched to a global variable it would be easier to deal with the data.

This is like the code looks like:

```
fetch('cars.json')
    .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        var startDate = new Date("2020-02-01");
        var endDate = new Date("2020-02-29");

        var resultProductData = myJson.filter(function (a) {
        var hitDates = a.DATE   || {};
        // extract all date strings
        hitDates = Object.keys(hitDates);
        // improvement: use some. this is an improment because .map()
        // and .filter() are walking through all elements.
        // .some() stops this process if one item is found that returns true in the callback function and returns true for the whole expression
        hitDateMatchExists = hitDates.some(function(dateStr) {
            var date = new Date(dateStr);
            return date >= startDate && date <= endDate
        });
        return hitDateMatchExists;
    });
    console.log(resultProductData);
    });
```

Thanks for helping me, I'm new with javascript.

Comment: Please show `cars.json` and what it should look like after filtering (the expected output). The fetch stuff is sort of irrelevant, assuming it works, so I recommend isolating the problem as a [mcve] and starting the question with the in-memory deserialized array of objects.

Comment: Whether the json is local or not is irrelevant if the question is about filtering data. Let's ignore the fetch code entirely, and focus on the part that _actually_ matters: given some `const data = ....`, being an object (not JSON: _JSON is by definition pure string data_ and has _no structure. It's a single string. You can parse it, but then it stops being JSON: now it's a normal JS object) what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to filter the json data by date so I can later chart this filtered data

Comment: The expected output is the data which is between the StartDate and the EndDate

Comment: It looks like `var resultProductData` is scoped to the `then()` block which means the call to `console.log(resultProductData)` which is outside that block will log `undefined`.

Comment: @kmoser how I could fix that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I filter an array of objects between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515607/how-can-i-filter-an-array-of-objects-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I will answer my question, I found this solution, I hope this could help someone dealing with the same stuff of filtering by date.

```
async function getData() {
    var startDate = "2020-02-01";
    var endDate = "2020-02-29";
    const response = await fetch('file.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    var result = data.filter(function(obj){
      return obj.DATE >= startDate && obj.DATE <= endDate;
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
```